# Cannot use the colour white except for Fonts. Frames and Buttons go gray (or other colour, depending on the shade)

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm trying to make a frame go white, however when I do it, let's say #FFFFFF, it goes gray. If I do #FFFAF0, it goes brown. Same goes with buttons. Fonts, however, white works.

I've repaired VS2022. No change. Tried removing stuff like Grids or StackLayouts, also nothing. Tried doing just a frame in a newly made project, frame is also gray.

```
<Frame Margin="10" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="True" Padding="100" CornerRadius="20">
```

Full code: https://srcshare.io/635eabb991c9d90707f83309

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What exactly have you tried already? Can you please show some code (as text using code blocks)?

Comment: Yes, show us some xaml that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead is stuffing code in the comments

Comment: Just edited original post. Should be good now. Thanks for the tips y'all!

Answer (score 1):

System Theme Change. The app adapts the colors according to Light Mode or Dark Mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
```